# Using max cell value as input in Raster Calculator of ArcGIS Pro

Tags: spatial-analyst, arcgis-pro, raster-calculator, con

I am using  ArcGIS Pro 2.4.

In the following equation, can "X" be replaced with the maximum cell value of another raster?  Alternately, replacing "X" with a field from a table would work.

```
Con("udlen", 1, 0, "Value > X")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.  [`Raster`](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/arcpy-classes/raster-object.htm) objects have a `maximum` property. Just make sure statistics have been calculated for the raster or `maximum` will return `None`.

E.g.

```
Con("my_raster.tif" > "other_raster.tif".maximum, value_if_true, value_if_false)
```

Comment: +1 never thought it's possible.

Comment: Yes!  Thank you user2856 - That solution worked perfectly!!

Comment: @FelixIP this has worked since ArcGIS10.0

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `MAXIMUM` argument in `arcpy.GetRasterProperties_management()` to get the highest cell value in the raster.  See the documentation for [Get Raster Properties (Data Management)](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/get-raster-properties.htm).

eg, `x = arcpy.GetRasterProperties_management("udlen", "MAXIMUM")`

Is that what you're after?

Comment: I'm using ModelBuilder and am hoping to populate the value within the raster calculator.  I also have the option of creating a table with the max value and have been trying to figure out how to extract the data from the table.  Looks like I need to step up my Python education - but I am hoping to do this within Model Builder for now.

Comment: The other answer from @user2856 looks like a better option, anyhow.

Comment: Thank you - I'll be trying your solution in Python also, I appreciate the input!